# Update a string parameter in Elasticsearch _mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have such a `_mapping` in `Elasticsearch` `6.8`:

```
{
  "grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "variant" : {
        "_meta" : {
          "gencodeVersion" : "25",
          "hail_version" : "0.2.20",
          "genomeVersion" : "38",
          "sampleType" : "WES",
          "sourceFilePath" : "s3://my_folder/my_vcf.vcf"
        },
    ...
```

My goal is to issue a query in `Kibana` to modify `variant._meta.sourceFilePath`. Following thread:

[Elastic search mapping for nested json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308817/elastic-search-mapping-for-nested-json-objects)

I was able to come up with the query:

```
PUT /grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/_mapping/variant
{
  "properties": {
    "variant": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "_meta": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "type": "text",
            "sourceFilePath": "s3://my_folder/my_vcf.vcf"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But its giving me an error:

[elasticsearch mapping Expected map for property [fields] on field [name] but got a class java.lang.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61378180/elasticsearch-mapping-expected-map-for-property-fields-on-field-name-but-got)

Full error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Expected map for property [fields] on field [type] but got a class java.lang.String"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Expected map for property [fields] on field [type] but got a class java.lang.String"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I have also tried:

```
PUT /grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/_mapping/variant
{
  "properties": {
    "variant": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "_meta": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "sourceFilePath": {
              "type": "text",
              "value":"s3://my_folder/my_vcf.vcf"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But its telling me that `value` is unsupported:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [sourceFilePath] has unsupported parameters:  [value : s3://seqr-dp-data--prod/vcf/dev/grch38_test_contracted.vcf]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Mapping definition for [sourceFilePath] has unsupported parameters:  [value : s3://seqr-dp-data--prod/vcf/dev/grch38_test_contracted.vcf]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How to modify the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_meta` is a reserved field for [storing application-specific metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-meta-field.html). It's not meant to be searchable and can be only retrieved through the [GET Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-get-mapping.html).

This means that if your `_meta` content was intended to be consistent with what the `_meta` field is designed for, you **cannot** apply any mappings to it. It's a "final" hashmap of concrete values and would need to be defined at the top level of your update-mapping payload:

```
PUT /grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/_mapping/variant
{
  "_meta": {
    "variant": {            <-- shared index-level metadata
      "gencodeVersion": "25",
      "hail_version": "0.2.20",
      "genomeVersion": "38",
      "sampleType": "WES",
      "sourceFilePath": "s3://my_folder/my_vcf.vcf"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "some_text_field": {    <-- actual document properties
      "type": "text" 
    }
  }
}
```

If, on the other hand, your `_meta` field is an **unfortunate naming coincidence**, you can declare the mappings for it like so:

```
PUT /grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/_mapping/variant
{
  "properties": {
    "_meta": {
      "properties": {
        "variant": {
          "properties": {
            "gencodeVersion": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "genomeVersion": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "hail_version": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "sampleType": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "sourceFilePath": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and ingest documents of the form:

```
POST grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/variant/_doc
{
  "_meta": {
    "variant": {
      "gencodeVersion": "25",
      "hail_version": "0.2.20",
      "genomeVersion": "38",
      "sampleType": "WES",
      "sourceFilePath": "s3://my_folder/my_vcf.vcf"
    }
  }
}
```

But again, the `_meta` content would be document-specific, not index-wide!

And BTW, the `nested` mapping only makes sense if you're dealing with [arrays of objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/nested.html), not objects of objects.
But if you insist on wanting it, here's how you'd do it:

```
PUT /grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/_mapping/variant?include_type_name
{
  "properties": {
    "_meta": {
      "type": "nested",            <---
      "properties": {
        "variant": {
          "type": "nested",        <---
          "properties": {
            "gencodeVersion": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "genomeVersion": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "hail_version": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "sampleType": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "sourceFilePath": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, does it mean (first case, `_meta` corresponds to what it should be) that `sourceFilePath` was defined at the moment of index creation and it is simply not allowed to be modified and there is no way to do that?

Comment: No -- you can modify the shared `_meta` attributes with my 1st snippet -- just make sure to remove the `properties` part.